# ¿Porque cuando entre a mi pagina web desde safari un elemento label cambia de color a azul?

Tags: html, css, safari

Cuando entro a mi pagina web desde el navegador safari una etiqueta:

```
<label>+52-55-78-95-42-48<label>(Numero de ejemplo)
```

cambia de color a un azul incluso poniendo Text-decoration y el color deseado

Espero puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto depende del **navegador**, es como los botones en los diferentes buscadores. No tiene el mismo diseño un botón predeterminado de **Chrome** que el botón predeterminado de **Firefox**.

Si ese texto es un `<p>`, `<a>` o alguno parecido, intenta colocar **`style="color: black"`** o el color que tu quieras.

Quedaría así

`<p style="color: black">Texto de ejemplo</p>`

o si es un `<a>`,

`<a style="color: black">Otro ejemplo</a>`

Espero que te sirva :)

Comment: Gracias lo probare

Comment: has puesto *buscador* en lugar de *navegador*

Comment: @blonfu arreglado, gracias por el fallo :)